# Urn model in R (trying to calculate probabilities for random events)

Tags: r, permutation, probability, combinatorics, urn

I really hope you can help me with a problem I cant solve on my own. 
I'm trying to program a basic urn model for a web app. I want to calculate the probabilities of specific random events according to different drawing methods in a model with 2 different colors.

The composition of the urn (red and black balls) is specified in a vector
a <-c(number_red, number_black)

The random event is specified in another vecotor, lets say
b<-c("red","red","black","red") or any other combination of red and black balls

Now want to calculate the probability of the event (vector b), when the balls are 
1) replaced in the urn, and order does matter 
2) NOT replaced in the urn, and order does matter
3) NOT replaced in the urn, and order doesn't matter
4) replaced in the urn, and order doesn't matter

I came up with several different ideas but none of them really worked...
At first I wrote fuctions in order to determine how many different combinations one can could draw in each of the scenarios.

```
stan = function(n,x) {return(n^x)}
perm = function(n, x) {return(factorial(n) / factorial(n-x))}
komb = function(n, x) {return(factorial(n) / (factorial(n-x)*factorial(x)))}
komb2 = function(n, x) {return(factorial(n+x-1) / (factorial(n-1)*factorial(x)))}
```

But then I didnt really know how to apply them in order to calculate the final probabilities.

I also experimented with for loops in order to emulate a tree diagram, but it became too complex for me. For example:

```
c <- c(number_red/(number_red+number_black), number_red/(number_red+number_black))
b <- c("red","black","red")
b[b=="red"]<-1
[b=="black"]<-2
b<-as.numeric(b)

vec<-NULL

for (i in b){
vec<-c(vec, c[i])}

prod(vec)
```

A solution like that gives correct results for problem #1, but i dont really know how to apply it to the other problems since I would have to find a way to alter vector c according to the composition of vector b each time I run the loop.

Of course I have experimented with different ideas, but none of them really seems to work. I would be very thankful if someone could help me with my problem.

Best,
Henry

Comment: in second code block , `c` is the proportion of balls, while in you text `c` is counts of balls, could you make this clear? and `c` is also the name of internal function, you may better chose other names.

Comment: I used the proportions because they represent the probabilities to draw a single ball. So each time the loop runs, either the probability of drawing a red ball or drawing a black ball is added to vec, according to the combosition of b. In the end all the single probabilities are multiplied in order to get the overall probability of b. Sorry i was not clear about that

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
a <- c(red = 5, black = 5)
b <- c("red","red","black","red")


# (1)
prod((a/sum(a))[b])

# (2)
p <- c()
n <- a
for(i in b){
    p <- c(n[i] / sum(n), p)
    n[i] <- n[i] - 1
}
prod(p)

# (3)
komb <- function(n, x) {
    return(factorial(n) / (factorial(n-x)*factorial(x)))
}

n <- table(b)

prod(sapply(names(n), function(i){
    komb(a[i], n[i])
})) / komb(sum(a), sum(n))

# (4)
# I think it is the same as (1) as each sample is independent;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful. The solutions for #1, 2 and 3 seem correct to me. However, # 4 is not the same as #1 since the order of the drawn balls doesnt matter. So the probability of the event should be higher than in scenario #1. I think one way to calculate it would be to multiply the result of #1 with the number of possible arangements or orders of b. In our example there are 4 different possible arrangements (i counted them)... But how can I calculate the number of possible arrangements if be is changing? Im looking for an abstract solution.

Comment: one thin i tried is this, but it doesnt give the right result (and it is probably very wrong since i tried to alter the solution to problem #3) komb2 = function(n, x) {return(factorial(n+x-1) / (factorial(n-1)*factorial(x)))}

n <- table(b)

prod(
  sapply(names(n), function(i){ 
    komb2(a[i], n[i])             
  })
)/ komb2(sum(a), sum(n))

Comment: Believe me, It is the same as 1.